# my android app crashes as soon as i want to make a new task

Tags: java, android, crash, nullpointerexception

hi guys im new to android and i want to make an app.something like a daily planner.
the problem is this, my app opens up and i have the new task button, when i hit the button to add a new task the app crashes. i searched the forum for similar problems but couldn't  get help.

here's my cat log file:

```
09-27 19:03:46.035: D/dalvikvm(19346): Late-enabling CheckJNI

09-27 19:03:46.440: D/dalvikvm(19346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 136K, 4% free 12874K/13319K, paused 31ms

09-27 19:03:46.440: I/dalvikvm-heap(19346): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.127MB for 379472-byte allocation

09-27 19:03:46.465: D/dalvikvm(19346): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 13245K/13703K, paused 20ms

09-27 19:03:46.535: D/AbsListView(19346): Get MotionRecognitionManager

09-27 19:03:49.510: D/CLIPBOARD(19346): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !

09-27 19:03:53.625: D/AndroidRuntime(19346): Shutting down VM

09-27 19:03:53.625: W/dalvikvm(19346): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5d1f8)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dailyplanner/com.example.dailyplanner.new_task}: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1894)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1851)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at com.example.dailyplanner.new_task.<init>(new_task.java:19)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1027)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1885)

09-27 19:03:53.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19346):    ... 11 more
```

this is the android manifest:

```
<manifest package="com.example.dailyplanner"
android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".new_task"/>
</application>
```

here is my main.java file:

```
package com.example.dailyplanner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null   );
    //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data1 (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, text VARCHAR, time TIME, date DATE)");



    Button nTaskBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nTask);
    nTaskBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent nTaskScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , new_task.class);



            startActivity(nTaskScreen);



        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and this is the new_task.java file:

```
package com.example.dailyplanner;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.net.UrlQuerySanitizer.ValueSanitizer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Sampler.Value;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class new_task extends Activity {

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID=0;
final TextView timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
TextView dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_task);

    Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {




        }
    });



    Button btnSetTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetTime);
    btnSetTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        }
        });
}
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                timeText.setText(hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                };

};
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    switch(id){

    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
    return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, true);

    }
    return null;

}
```

Any help?

Comment: this is alot of code to look through, can you try to narrow it down to where the problem is ?

Comment: i knwo it is a lot of code, but that's the problem, i dont see any errors on my code so i can narrow it down, from the log cat i can say too look into that nullpointerexeption, but i'm new into this, and i dont really know what im doing wrong:S

Comment: i dont think you need to have import android.R.string; line once remove the line and check if you are getting any errors on anyof the line

Comment: try doing a small help for us.
try clicking on the logcat errors and on one or the other point you will be moved to the java file which might be the main point of the error . try checking it

Comment: i didnt get errors from removing the R.string line, although as Samir suggested below

i did this, 
`in new_task Activity,Put these refrences

final TextView timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
TextView dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);

after setContentView(R.layout.new_task);`

now there is an error timepicker dialog function and it says that _timeText_ cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use findViewById after you set the content view. It is also useful to null check variables before accessing them. Finally, make sure that the layout file R.layout.new_task contains items with the ids timeTxt, dateTxt, btnSave.

I re-wrote some of your work to give you an example of what I mean:

```
private TextView timeText;
private TextView dateText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_task);

    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
    dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateTxt);

    Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    if (btnSave != null) {
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    } else {
        Log.e("MyActivity", "btnSave was null :(");
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx jimmyyy! :D..that was it,
i just needed to delcare the timetext and date text before the on create and with the findview... after oncreate, that did the trick,

btw stnsave wasn't null, it just didnt have the code for saving the info in it, im gonna add it later...thanx a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `findViewById()` in `onCreate()` **after** the call to `setContentView()`.